# Why is the magnitude of the unit circle only 1 for positive inputs?

Tags: complex-numbers, matlab, absolute-value

During computations with Matlab (Symbolic Math) a formula with the absolute value of a complex number came up. The expression consists of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ terms, which lead to the absolute value not being simplified. I tracked the problem down and found that the expression $|sin(x)+i\cdot cos(x)|$ only computes to equal $1$ if $x$ is assumed positive.

What is the explanation for this since the plot of this function equal $1$ for any $x$?

EDIT: As explained in the comments and first answer I understand that if $x$ is complex the expression doesn't necessarily equal $1$. But even if declaring $x$ to be real, Matlab cannot compute the absolute value. Only after saying $x>0$, similar to the answer that Wolfram|Alpha gives (under: *Alternate form assuming x is positive*): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Csin%28x%29%2Bi*+cos%28x%29%7C

EDIT 2: Nevermind about the Matlab-Part of the question. It is indeed enough to specify that $x$ should be real.

Comment: If $x$ is a complex number than this expression need not equal $1$. If $x$ is real Matlab should be able to simplify this to $1$.

Comment: The absolute value is $1$ for every real $x$ , also negative $x$

Comment: @quarague Since you responded first, if you could post something like that as an answer, this question could no longer appear as if it has no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is a complex number than this expression need not equal 1. If $x$ is real Matlab should be able to simplify this to $1$. It seems that in general Matlab assumes numbers to be complex if not told otherwise. If you tell it that $x>0$, this implicitly also means that $x$ is real, hence Matlab simplifies successfully.

Comment: As a test of this, one should try assuming $x<0$ instead and verify that Maple still handles it properly.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm sure one can tell Maple that a variable is real directly.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that but: see edit ;)